# C# CenterParent using ShowDialog not working

Tags: c#, forms, position

I'm having trouble getting a child form to center itself wrt its parent. I've been trying all sorts of suggestions ranging from using or not using ShowDialog to all kinds of whacky "Calculate your form's position" code.

This really shouldn't be so complex, I think.

Anyway, here's some code. The following code is where I instantiate the form and ask it to open. The `this` in this code is the MainForm.

```
FormName myForm = new FormName();
myForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

I have set the form's `StartPosition` to `CenterParent` but if I move the MainForm around and reopen the form, it doesn't follow along. In fact, it stays right where it is no matter what. It's not even center-screen!

In the form's constructor, I do not set anything wrt the form's position.

I also do not set anything wrt the form's position in the Load method of the form.

Please help!

Edit:
I've tried stepping through the constructor and load methods of the form to see if they bailout before finishing and they work just fine.

Comment: You may need to post more code. This works for me every time.

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that adding code to the constructor of a form is a bad idea and causes all sorts of weird behavior. Instead, one should add code for the form on the Form Load event. This was the root of my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this soln, I have been trying for a long time to get this right, but as you mentioned, it must be explicitly defined in the codes. Doesnt even work if you set it from the properties

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me:

```
var MainForm = new Form();
var SubForm = new Form {
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent,
    Width = 200,
    Height = 200,
};

MainForm.MouseClick += (sender, args) => { SubForm.ShowDialog(MainForm); };
MainForm.Show();
```

When you double click the MainForm it opens the SubForm centered to it. Then when you close the subform and move the MainForm, when double click on the MainForm again, the SubForm again shows up centered to the MainForm.

Comment: Hi @luisprerezphd, essentially this is the same code I'm using. Yours is just very concentrated and mine is spread out through the resx and MainForm.cs files

Comment: @Kashif as far as I can see the only two things that matter is that the subform has it's `StartPosition` set to `FormStartPosition.CenterParent` and that it be shown using `ShowDialog()` with the Form you want it centered passed as a parameter. If it's not center you should run the debugger to check the value of `StartPosition` is on the subform just before ShowDialog() is called. How are you assigning the `StartPosition` now?

Comment: I am assigning the `StartPosition` field via the form's properties